# Sharepoint farm solution recycle which application pool?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, application-pool, farm-solution

I have SharePoint Project which deploy as Farm Solution. I have multiple Web Application (SPWebApplication) in SharePoint. Each Web Application has dedicated application pool. I want to know if I deploy project as Farm Solution then all  application pool recycles or particular one application pool will recycle ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the application pool of your SharePoint project will recycle. Note that you define the site url in properties window of your project. Then when you deploy the project note that in "Output" window, you can see:

```
Recycle IIS Application Pool: 
    Recycling IIS application pool '<application pool name>'...
```

So just the application pool related to your site url will recycle.

Answer (score 0):

Your farm solution can be deployed to multiple web applications. If that is the case then all web applications where the solution is deployed will recycle.

It's also important that you specify the -WebApplication parameter in your Install-SPSolution and Uninstall-SPSolution scripts, as they might otherwise recycle all web applications.